# MySQL is not using index on very simple GROUP BY query

Tags: mysql, indexing, group-by, grouping

Here is my table create/schema:

`` CREATE TABLE `_test` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `group_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `total` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `group_id` (`group_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ``

So 2 keys - PRIMARY on id and INDEX on group_id.

and here is a data sample:

[image]

Now, the thing is that when I run EXPLAIN for the following simple query:

`EXPLAIN SELECT SUM( total ) FROM _test GROUP BY (group_id)`

I am getting no use of any key despite one being clearly created on group_id column:

[image]

any ideas why MySQL is not trying to use group_id index for that query?

Comment: Using the index on `id` wouldn't help at all because for your query MySQL still needs to read all rows of the table. If at all, an index on `(id, total)` would help

Comment: I am not asking about id index but about group_id index, why is it not used when GROUP BY involves group_id field which has index on it?

Comment: Try adding more test data and a range of group Ids and see if the index starts being used. For a small table or when the index is not very selective, it is faster to do the table scan. Mysql isn't very good at communicating what is going on so that may be why you don't see the index used.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `group_id` btw: for only two rows, using an index never makes sense

Comment: It does but the solution is that all GROUP BY columns reference attributes from the same index, e.g. the following index - `(group_id,total)` satisfies the query entirely off the index even if there are just 2 rows

Comment: mdatwood is spot on here... because you have only two rows and, more importantly, the fact that both of them have the same exact group id, MySQL is going to read the entire table. It has to. There's only one value of groupid. Using the index won't make any sense (unless you use the covering index technique mentioned by Marcin... just looked into that, and it will work just fine in MyISAM. Depending on the size of the table, that's definitely something to consider)

Comment: size has nothing to do here, those 2 rows is just an example, same thing happen whether you have 2 or 2 millions so please don't get fixated on the example but on the problem. As per my comment above creating the following index - (group_id,total) - will get MySQL to use index completely even if there is just 1 row.